# Weighted means for groups in r - using aggregate and weighted.mean functions together

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the weighted mean for group variable X1, across all numeric variables, here is some example data

```
set.seed(123)
X1=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4)
Y1=as.numeric(seq(1,12,by=1))
Y2=sample(1:5,12,TRUE)
Y3=sample(10:20,12,TRUE)
wgt <- abs(rnorm(12)*10)
df <- data.frame(X1,Y1,Y2,Y3,wgt)
```

This is the code I've been using to calculate regular mean values for X1

```
aggregate( df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)] , by=list(df$X1) , FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I want to calculate weight mean, weight variable is **wgt**. I tried both of these codes and neither work. I've tried numerous different ways and nothing is working.

```
aggregate( df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)] , by=list(df$X1) , FUN=weighted.mean(x, w=df$wgt), na.rm = TRUE)
aggregate( df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)] , by=list(df$X1) , FUN=weighted.mean, w=df$wgt, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I'm unable to adapt the **weighted.mean** function. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Can this function even be used in this situation?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to compute the weighted means with `aggregate` called by `by()`.

```
res <- by(df, df$X1, function(DF){
  aggregate(cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ X1, DF, function(y, w) 
    weighted.mean(y, w = DF[['wgt']], na.rm = TRUE))
})
do.call(rbind, res)
#  X1        Y1       Y2       Y3
#A  A  2.152503 2.633935 18.93457
#B  B  6.677851 3.589251 16.90102
#C  C 10.194695 2.638378 16.70958
```

Comment: instead of specifying each variable with cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) . Is it possible to select all numeric variables, like I did with the is.numeric() function?

Comment: @H.Cheung I don't believe that's possible, or at least not simpler. That's a problem with the LHS of formulas. See [Chuck P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264585/8245406) for a dplyr solution that does precisely that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `outer` to apply `weighted.mean` crosswise.

```
gr <- c("A", "B", "C"); ys <- c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3")
WF <- Vectorize(function(x, y) with(df[df$X1 %in% x, ], weighted.mean(get(y), wgt)))
res <- `dimnames<-`(outer(gr, ys, WF), list(gr, ys))
res
#          Y1       Y2       Y3
# A  2.152503 2.633935 18.93457
# B  6.677851 3.589251 16.90102
# C 10.194695 2.638378 16.70958
```

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't provide the answer you originally posted. I added the edit to your post. To manually calculate weighted mean, it needs to be multiplied by the weight, then divided by the sum of that weight for the respective X1 group to get the weighted mean. Multiplying it by the weight just inflates the mean value. Thanks for your time anyway

Comment: @H.Cheung Many thanks for the pointer! Apparently I was irritated by several results on the console and assigned a wrong result to the code too quickly. I suggest an alternative solution with `outer`, see edit!

Comment: that works well. That's an interesting way to do it. Many thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that returns the same answers as @Rui.  As requested this will operate on all variables that are numeric regardless of their column name.

```r
df %>% 
   group_by(X1) %>% 
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
                    ~ weighted.mean(.x, wgt), 
                    .names = "weighted_mean_{.col}"))
```